# Callback Problem with Multiple Subscribers

Tags: ros, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working on a project which scans rooms and builds the complete map of the room.
The ros code that I wrote requires multiple subscribers (eg for Pose and Obstacles).
I want the subscription to be sequential. However with the use of spin() or spinOnce() my program gets stuck in the first callback function. How do I solve this problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12389/callback-problem-with-multiple-subscribers/) by [Ruchi Dhiman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1486/ruchi-dhiman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2011-12-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What do you mean sequential?

ROS data comes from the system, whenever it is published.

If you want to match arriving data [message filters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters) might be, what you need.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-26**:
Documentation of threading is at http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning